# Pandas Melt Columns to Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

I have data that looks like this:

| Date | Country | Channel | App-Purchase-Laptop | App-Purchase-Cell | App-Sell-Laptop | App-Sell-Cell | Web-Purchase-Laptop | Web-Purchase-Cell | Web-Sell-Laptop | Web-Sell-Cell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/25 | US | Email | 6 | 10 | 30 | 40 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 11 |
| 03/25 | US | Direct | 1 | 30 | 10 | 20 | 6 | 8 | 10 | 12 |
| 03/25 | India | Email | 4 | 60 | 29 | 37 | 40 | 21 | 43 | 53 |
| 03/25 | India | Direct | 11 | 16 | 32 | 22 | 39 | 11 | 7 | 45 |
| 03/26 | US | Email | 6 | 10 | 30 | 40 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 11 |
| 03/26 | US | Direct | 1 | 30 | 10 | 20 | 6 | 8 | 10 | 12 |
| 03/26 | India | Email | 4 | 60 | 29 | 37 | 40 | 21 | 43 | 53 |
| 03/26 | India | Direct | 11 | 16 | 32 | 22 | 39 | 11 | 7 | 45 |

Output I am looking for:

| Date | Country | Channel | Category | Source | Purchase | Sell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/25 | US | Email | App | Laptop | 6 | 30 |
| 03/25 | US | Email | App | Cell | 10 | 40 |
| 03/25 | US | Email | Web | Laptop | 5 | 9 |
| 03/25 | US | Email | Web | Cell | 7 | 11 |
| 03/25 | US | Direct | App | Laptop | 1 | 10 |
| 03/25 | US | Direct | App | Cell | 30 | 20 |
| 03/25 | US | Direct | Web | Laptop | 6 | 10 |
| 03/25 | US | Direct | Web | Cell | 8 | 12 |
| 03/25 | India | Email | App | Laptop | 4 | 30 |
| 03/25 | India | Email | App | Cell | 60 | 29 |
| 03/25 | India | Email | Web | Laptop | 40 | 43 |
| 03/25 | India | Email | Web | Cell | 21 | 53 |
| 03/25 | India | Direct | App | Laptop | 11 | 32 |
| 03/25 | India | Direct | App | Cell | 16 | 22 |
| 03/25 | India | Direct | Web | Laptop | 39 | 7 |
| 03/25 | India | Direct | Web | Cell | 11 | 45 |
| 03/26 | US | Email | App | Laptop | 6 | 30 |
| 03/26 | US | Email | App | Cell | 10 | 40 |
| 03/26 | US | Email | Web | Laptop | 5 | 9 |
| 03/26 | US | Email | Web | Cell | 7 | 11 |
| 03/26 | US | Direct | App | Laptop | 1 | 10 |
| 03/26 | US | Direct | App | Cell | 30 | 20 |
| 03/26 | US | Direct | Web | Laptop | 6 | 10 |
| 03/26 | US | Direct | Web | Cell | 8 | 12 |
| 03/26 | India | Email | App | Laptop | 4 | 30 |
| 03/26 | India | Email | App | Cell | 60 | 29 |
| 03/26 | India | Email | Web | Laptop | 40 | 43 |
| 03/26 | India | Email | Web | Cell | 21 | 53 |
| 03/26 | India | Direct | App | Laptop | 11 | 32 |
| 03/26 | India | Direct | App | Cell | 16 | 22 |
| 03/26 | India | Direct | Web | Laptop | 39 | 7 |
| 03/26 | India | Direct | Web | Cell | 11 | 45 |

I tried different ways to solve this using melt, but I have been unable to solve this since I am new to python. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
dfi = df.set_index(['Date','Country','Channel'])

dfi.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(dfi.columns.str.split('-', expand=True), 
                                        names=['Category', None, 'Source'])

df_out = dfi.stack([0,2]).reset_index()

df_out
```

Output:

```
     Date Country Channel Category  Source  Purchase  Sell
0   03/25      US   Email      App    Cell        10    40
1   03/25      US   Email      App  Laptop         6    30
2   03/25      US   Email      Web    Cell         7    11
3   03/25      US   Email      Web  Laptop         5     9
4   03/25      US  Direct      App    Cell        30    20
5   03/25      US  Direct      App  Laptop         1    10
6   03/25      US  Direct      Web    Cell         8    12
7   03/25      US  Direct      Web  Laptop         6    10
8   03/25   India   Email      App    Cell        60    37
9   03/25   India   Email      App  Laptop         4    29
10  03/25   India   Email      Web    Cell        21    53
11  03/25   India   Email      Web  Laptop        40    43
12  03/25   India  Direct      App    Cell        16    22
13  03/25   India  Direct      App  Laptop        11    32
14  03/25   India  Direct      Web    Cell        11    45
15  03/25   India  Direct      Web  Laptop        39     7
16  03/26      US   Email      App    Cell        10    40
17  03/26      US   Email      App  Laptop         6    30
18  03/26      US   Email      Web    Cell         7    11
19  03/26      US   Email      Web  Laptop         5     9
20  03/26      US  Direct      App    Cell        30    20
21  03/26      US  Direct      App  Laptop         1    10
22  03/26      US  Direct      Web    Cell         8    12
23  03/26      US  Direct      Web  Laptop         6    10
24  03/26   India   Email      App    Cell        60    37
25  03/26   India   Email      App  Laptop         4    29
26  03/26   India   Email      Web    Cell        21    53
27  03/26   India   Email      Web  Laptop        40    43
28  03/26   India  Direct      App    Cell        16    22
29  03/26   India  Direct      App  Laptop        11    32
30  03/26   India  Direct      Web    Cell        11    45
31  03/26   India  Direct      Web  Laptop        39     7
```

Details:

Let's move Date, Country, and Channel into the index, now use string manipulation on the remaining columns to create a multiindex column header.  Finally, stack the Category and Source levels into index and reset index.

​

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to abstract the reshaping process (it is just a wrapper around `melt` and some pandas string methods):

```
df.pivot_longer(index = ['Date','Country','Channel'], 
                names_to=['Category', '.value', 'Source'], 
                names_sep="-", 
                sort_by_appearance = True)
 
     Date Country Channel Category  Source  Purchase  Sell
0   03/25      US   Email      App  Laptop         6    30
1   03/25      US   Email      App    Cell        10    40
2   03/25      US   Email      Web  Laptop         5     9
3   03/25      US   Email      Web    Cell         7    11
4   03/25      US  Direct      App  Laptop         1    10
5   03/25      US  Direct      App    Cell        30    20
6   03/25      US  Direct      Web  Laptop         6    10
7   03/25      US  Direct      Web    Cell         8    12
8   03/25   India   Email      App  Laptop         4    29
9   03/25   India   Email      App    Cell        60    37
10  03/25   India   Email      Web  Laptop        40    43
11  03/25   India   Email      Web    Cell        21    53
12  03/25   India  Direct      App  Laptop        11    32
13  03/25   India  Direct      App    Cell        16    22
14  03/25   India  Direct      Web  Laptop        39     7
15  03/25   India  Direct      Web    Cell        11    45
16  03/26      US   Email      App  Laptop         6    30
17  03/26      US   Email      App    Cell        10    40
18  03/26      US   Email      Web  Laptop         5     9
19  03/26      US   Email      Web    Cell         7    11
20  03/26      US  Direct      App  Laptop         1    10
21  03/26      US  Direct      App    Cell        30    20
22  03/26      US  Direct      Web  Laptop         6    10
23  03/26      US  Direct      Web    Cell         8    12
24  03/26   India   Email      App  Laptop         4    29
25  03/26   India   Email      App    Cell        60    37
26  03/26   India   Email      Web  Laptop        40    43
27  03/26   India   Email      Web    Cell        21    53
28  03/26   India  Direct      App  Laptop        11    32
29  03/26   India  Direct      App    Cell        16    22
30  03/26   India  Direct      Web  Laptop        39     7
31  03/26   India  Direct      Web    Cell        11    45
```

Your data has a pattern : `category`, followed by either `Purchase` or `Sell` and finally followed by `Source`. the separator here is `-`. the pattern in `names_to` (Category, '.value', 'Source') keeps values paired with `.value` as column names, while the others are lumped into either `Category` or `Source`, depending on position.